# Merging Ranges using Sets - Error - Stack level too deep (SystemStackError)

Tags: ruby, runtime-error

I have a number of ranges that I want merge together if they overlap. The way I’m currently doing this is by using Sets.

This is working. However, when I attempt the same code with a larger ranges as follows, I get a `stack level too deep (SystemStackError).

```
require 'set'

ranges = [Range.new(73, 856), Range.new(82, 1145), Range.new(116, 2914), Range.new(3203, 3241)]
set = Set.new
ranges.each { |r| set << r.to_set }
set.flatten!
sets_subsets = set.divide { |i, j| (i - j).abs == 1 } # this line causes the error

puts sets_subsets
```

The line that is failing is taken directly from the [Ruby Set Documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html#method-i-divide).

I would appreciate it if anyone could suggest a fix or an alternative that works for the above example

**EDIT**

I have put the full code I’m using here:

Basically it is used to add html tags to an amino acid sequence according to some features.

```
require 'set'

def calculate_formatting_classes(hsps, signalp)
  merged_hsps = merge_ranges(hsps)
  sp          = format_signalp(merged_hsps, signalp)
  hsp_class   = (merged_hsps - sp[1]) - sp[0]
  rank_format_positions(sp, hsp_class)
end

def merge_ranges(ranges)
  set = Set.new
  ranges.each { |r| set << r.to_set }
  set.flatten
end

def format_signalp(merged_hsps, sp)
  sp_class     = sp - merged_hsps
  sp_hsp_class = sp & merged_hsps # overlap regions between sp & merged_hsp
  [sp_class, sp_hsp_class]
end

def rank_format_positions(sp, hsp_class)
  results = []
  results += sets_to_hash(sp[0], 'sp')
  results += sets_to_hash(sp[1], 'sphsp')
  results += sets_to_hash(hsp_class, 'hsp')
  results.sort_by { |s| s[:pos] }
end

def sets_to_hash(set = nil, cl)
  return nil if set.nil?
  hashes = []
  merged_set = set.divide { |i, j| (i - j).abs == 1 }
  merged_set.each do |s|
    hashes << { pos: s.min.to_i - 1, insert: "<span class=#{cl}>" }
    hashes << { pos: s.max.to_i - 0.1, insert: '</span>' } # for ordering
  end
  hashes
end

working_hsp = [Range.new(7, 136), Range.new(143, 178)]
not_working_hsp = [Range.new(73, 856), Range.new(82, 1145),
                   Range.new(116, 2914), Range.new(3203, 3241)]

sp = Range.new(1, 20).to_set

# working
results = calculate_formatting_classes(working_hsp, sp)

# Not Working
# results = calculate_formatting_classes(not_working_hsp, sp)

puts results
```

Comment: i think your set is just too large for `.divide`. I suspect it needs to run 2881^2881 iterations to go through it.

Comment: @kimmmo, makes sense, any suggestions for an alternative?

Comment: Can you share sample input and expected output? The sample input should work without stack error for your code so that one can understand what you need.

Comment: @WandMakerm I have added some sample code with a working and not working example

Comment: Thanks for posting your code.  You missed to mention what was your expected output when you say `Not working`.  Also have a look at [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for your future reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to do this:

```
ranges = [Range.new(73, 856), Range.new(82, 1145), 
          Range.new(116, 2914), Range.new(3203, 3241)]

ranges.size.times do
  ranges = ranges.sort_by(&:begin)
  t = ranges.each_cons(2).to_a
  t.each do |r1, r2| 
    if (r2.cover? r1.begin) || (r2.cover? r1.end) || 
       (r1.cover? r2.begin) || (r1.cover? r2.end)
      ranges << Range.new([r1.begin, r2.begin].min, [r1.end, r2.end].max)
      ranges.delete(r1)
      ranges.delete(r2)
      t.delete [r1,r2] 
    end
  end
end


p ranges
#=> [73..2914, 3203..3241]
```

Answer (score 2):

The other answers aren't bad, but I prefer a simple recursive approach:

```
def merge_ranges(*ranges)
  range, *rest = ranges
  return if range.nil?

  # Find the index of the first range in `rest` that overlaps this one
  other_idx = rest.find_index do |other|
    range.cover?(other.begin) || other.cover?(range.begin)
  end

  if other_idx
    # An overlapping range was found; remove it from `rest` and merge
    # it with this one
    other = rest.slice!(other_idx)
    merged = ([range.begin, other.begin].min)..([range.end, other.end].max)

    # Try again with the merged range and the remaining `rest`
    merge_ranges(merged, *rest)
  else
    # No overlapping range was found; move on
    [ range, *merge_ranges(*rest) ]
  end
end
```

**Note:** This code assumes each range is ascending (e.g. `10..5` will break it).

Usage:

```
ranges = [ 73..856, 82..1145, 116..2914, 3203..3241 ]
p merge_ranges(*ranges)
# => [73..2914, 3203..3241]

ranges = [ 0..10, 5..20, 30..50, 45..80, 50..90, 100..101, 101..200 ]
p merge_ranges(*ranges)
# => [0..20, 30..90, 100..200]
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe your resulting set has too many items (2881) to be used with `divide`, which if I understood correctly, would require 2881^2881 iterations, which is such a big number (8,7927981983090337174360463368808e+9966) that running it would take nearly forever even if you didn't get stack level too deep error.

Without using sets, you can use this code to merge the ranges:

```
module RangeMerger
  def merge(range_b)
    if cover?(range_b.first) && cover?(range_b.last)
      self
    elsif cover?(range_b.first)
      self.class.new(first, range_b.last)
    elsif cover?(range_b.last)
      self.class.new(range_b.first, last)
    else
      nil # Unmergable
    end
  end
end

module ArrayRangePusher
  def <<(item)
    if item.kind_of?(Range)
      item.extend RangeMerger
      each_with_index do |own_item, idx|
        own_item.extend RangeMerger
        if new_range = own_item.merge(item)
          self[idx] = new_range
          return self
        end
      end
    end
    super
  end
end

ranges = [Range.new(73, 856), Range.new(82, 1145), Range.new(116, 2914), Range.new(3203, 3241)]

new_ranges = Array.new
new_ranges.extend ArrayRangePusher

ranges.each do |range|
  new_ranges << range
end
puts ranges.inspect
puts new_ranges.inspect
```

This will output:

```
[73..856, 82..1145, 116..2914, 3203..3241]
[73..2914, 3203..3241]
```

which I believe is the intended output for your original problem. It's a bit ugly, but I'm a bit rusty at the moment.

Edit: I don't think this has anything to do with your original problem before the edits which was about merging ranges.

Comment: Thanks @kimmmo, However, I’m not sure if I can incorporate this into my actual code (but I’ll have a go at it in a bit) - see edit..